# update data in custom adapter using swipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley, android-json

I am trying to update the data using swipeRefreshLayout, but every time I swipe down to refresh it repeats the old ones instead of showing the new data.

Can you please help me with that and show me where did i make the mistake and how to fix it.

My code in fragment:

```
public class StoriesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String url = "http://sho3a3.net/storiesfeed.json";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<StoriesItem> storiesListItem = new ArrayList<StoriesItem>();
    private ListView storiesListView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    public StoriesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stories_fragment, container, false);

        /*Swipe Refresh Layout*/

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getDataFromUrl();
            }

        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(
                android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);


        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                getDataFromUrl();
            }
        });

        storiesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), storiesListItem);
        storiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*Click Feed Item */
        storiesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Object o = storiesListView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                StoriesItem storiesItem = (StoriesItem) o;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("storiesItem", storiesItem);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void getDataFromUrl() {

        // RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        //hidePDialog();

                        String title;
                        String date;
                        String profession;
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                StoriesItem storiesItem = new StoriesItem();

                                //Title
                                title = obj.getString("title");
                                byte[] bytesTitle = title.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                                String stringTitle = new String(bytesTitle, "UTF-8");
                                storiesItem.setTitle(stringTitle);

                                //Date
                                date = obj.getString("date");
                                byte[] bytesDate = date.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                                String stringDate = new String(bytesDate, "UTF-8");
                                storiesItem.setDate(stringDate);


                                //Profession
                                profession = obj.getString("profession");
                                byte[] bytesProfession = profession.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                                String stringProfession = new String(bytesProfession, "UTF-8");
                                storiesItem.setProfession(stringProfession);


                                storiesItem.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                storiesItem.setContent(obj.getString("content"));


                                // adding movie to movies array
                                storiesListItem.add(storiesItem);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        onItemsLoadComplete();
                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data


                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                //hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        //requestQueue.add(movieReq);
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    void onItemsLoadComplete() {
        // Update the adapter and notify data set changed
        // ...
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Stop refresh animation
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    public void onUpdate() {
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), storiesListItem);
        storiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What your getDataFromUrl is doing is just getting some datas from the server and adding them into storiesListItem. Doing just that, the previous items in storiesListItem will not disappear magically :-) .

What you should do instead is clear that list before every refreshing like this :

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             storiesListItem.clear();
                getDataFromUrl();
 }
```

instead of  :

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getDataFromUrl();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you would rather clear your list before you parse another set of JSON instead of onRefresh() so that the list will still remain on the background while refreshing. Like this:

```
String title;
String date;
String profession;

if(response.length() > 0) {
    // CLear list here
    storiesListItem.clear();

    // Parsing json
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
```